# pyspark find monthly re-engaged user

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Have a large dataframe looks like this, need to find monthly reengaged users number, which means if a user did not visit last month but come back this month.

If only need to compare two months it will be easy. How to do this month over month more efficiently.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("2020-05-06", "1"),
        ("2020-05-07", "1"),
        ("2020-05-08", "2"),
        ("2020-05-10", "3"),
        ("2020-05-07", "3"),
        ("2020-05-07", "1"),
        ("2020-05-20", "4"),
        ("2020-05-30", "2"),
        ("2020-05-03", "1"),
        ("2020-06-06", "1"),
        ("2020-06-07", "1"),
        ("2020-06-08", "5"),
        ("2020-06-10", "3"),
        ("2020-06-07", "3"),
        ("2020-06-07", "1"),
        ("2020-06-20", "3"),
        ("2020-06-30", "5"),
        ("2020-07-03", "2"),
        ("2020-07-06", "4"),
        ("2020-07-07", "4"),
        ("2020-07-08", "2"),
        ("2020-07-10", "3"),
        ("2020-07-07", "3"),
        ("2020-07-07", "4"),
        ("2020-07-20", "3"),
        ("2020-07-30", "2"),
        ("2020-08-03", "1"),
        ("2020-08-03", "2"),
        ("2020-08-06", "5"),
        ("2020-08-07", "4"),
        ("2020-08-08", "2"),
        ("2020-08-10", "3"),
        ("2020-08-07", "3"),
        ("2020-08-07", "4"),
        ("2020-08-20", "3"),
        ("2020-08-30", "2"),
        ("2020-08-03", "1"),
    ],
    ["visit_date", "userId"],
)

df = df.withColumn("first_day_month", F.trunc("visit_date", "month")).withColumn(
    "first_day_last_month", F.expr("add_months(first_day_month, -1)")
)

s5 = df.where(F.col("first_day_month") == "2020-05-01")
s6 = df.where(F.col("first_day_month") == "2020-06-01").withColumnRenamed(
    "userId", "userId_right"
)


ss = s5.join(s6, s5.userId == s6.userId_right, how="right")
ss.select("userId_right").where(F.col("userId").isNull()).show()
```

Spark array manipulation seems also worth trying but needs to do a row by row

array_interset calculation which I'm not familiar with it yet also not sure if it's efficient to run this way

```
dd = (
    df.groupby("first_day_month")
    .agg(F.collect_list("userId").alias("users_current_month"))
    .orderBy("first_day_month")
)
dd.show()


+---------------+-------------------+
|first_day_month|users_current_month|
+---------------+-------------------+
|     2020-05-01|       [1, 2, 3, 4]|
|     2020-06-01|          [1, 3, 5]|
|     2020-07-01|          [2, 3, 4]|
|     2020-08-01|    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|
+---------------+-------------------+
```

Any idea?

expected results:

```
first_day_month    reengaged_user_count
2020-06-01         1
2020-07-01         2
2020-08-01         2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using analytics function, we can do something like this :

```py
df = df.withColumn("first_day_month", F.trunc("visit_date", "month")).withColumn(
    "first_day_last_month",
    F.lag("first_day_month").over(Window.partitionBy("userId").orderBy("visit_date")),
)
ss = df.where(F.months_between("first_day_month", "first_day_last_month") > 1)
ss.show()

+----------+------+---------------+--------------------+
|visit_date|userId|first_day_month|first_day_last_month|
+----------+------+---------------+--------------------+
|2020-08-06|     5|     2020-08-01|          2020-06-01|
|2020-08-03|     1|     2020-08-01|          2020-06-01|
|2020-07-06|     4|     2020-07-01|          2020-05-01|
|2020-07-03|     2|     2020-07-01|          2020-05-01|
+----------+------+---------------+--------------------+


ss.groupBy("first_day_month").agg(F.collect_set("UserId")).show()

+---------------+-------------------+
|first_day_month|collect_set(UserId)|
+---------------+-------------------+
|     2020-08-01|             [1, 5]|
|     2020-07-01|             [2, 4]|
+---------------+-------------------+
```